# Is there a shorthand css property like "all:" but for unspecified properties?

Tags: css, revert, shorthand, css-cascade

Let's say I have two different stylesheets that are setting values to unique properties on the div element with class="example".

Stylesheet A:

```
    .example {
        background-color: #000;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: #fff;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        line-height: 25px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Stylesheet B:

```
    div{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
    }
```

Is there a shorthand property and value similar to `all: revert;` that I could add to the Stylesheet A to set all undeclared properties to the browser default and essentially overwrite/erase the Stylesheet B? In my mind, it would be something like `remaining: revert;`.

If there is not such a shorthand property, is there some other trick I could do without explicitly having to list all the properties that haven't been declared in Stylesheet A and applying 'revert'? Bonus points if I could apply this trick recursively to the elements within the div with > and/or * selectors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the thing is, styles getting applied in the manner/order they are specified. Like `broweser styles -> first style sheet -> second style sheet etc`. So you can't override the styles specified in the second style sheet with something that applied before, unless you use the `!important`

Comment: Thank you. Not the answer I was looking for, but to clarify, the stylesheets in my post are not necessarily loaded in that order and each one has unique properties that aren't overwriting each other.

With that in mind and assuming "Stylesheet 1" is loaded after "Stylesheet 2", is there a way to apply the 'revert' value to all undeclared properties without explicitly listing all of them individually?

Comment: I don't think there is any way

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a one-size-fits-all way to do this due to how cascade resolution for the `all` property works (so the bonus question doesn't have a universal answer, it depends entirely on the project). The CSS cascade does not compartmentalize rules and declarations by the stylesheet they appear in — all author-origin styles are consolidated to a single logical "stylesheet" in the order they appear in, and cascade resolution is performed accordingly. This means equally specific styles in later stylesheets will take precedence, whereas *more* specific styles in *earlier* stylesheets will take precedence.

In this case, because `.example` happens to be more specific than `div`, placing an `all: reset` declaration at the *top* of the `.example` rule will give you the desired effect (assuming there are no other style declarations elsewhere you would like to preserve, or more specific declarations elsewhere you would like removed as those would continue to apply even if you do this):

```css
.example {
    all: revert;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* ... */
```

Everything in `.example` appearing after the `all: revert` declaration will be unaffected by it.

In the following code snippet you can compare the results of applying `all: revert` this way, against an element without the declaration:

```css
.example:where(:first-of-type) {
    all: revert;
}

.example {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

div{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p>Inspect each element's styles to see the effects of <code>all: revert</code>
<div class="example">1</div>
<div class="example">2</div>
```

Or, see the following screenshots of Firefox's Inspector:

Element 1:

[image: .example:where(:first-of-type) rule with all: revert declaration, followed by div rule with its declarations struck out on Element 1]

Element 2:

[image: div rule with its declarations still active on Element 2]

Comment: Thank you very for taking the time to explain this and the solution I was looking for.